# Having an issue with dojo checkedMultiselect when I need a default checked and uncheckable causing all options to be uncheckable

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I have a dojo widjet CheckedMultiselect with several options in it. I am creating it programmatically as the options will change based on the selection of a different dropdown.

The issue I am running into is that one of the options always has to be checked and it cannot be unchecked. I found a way to make that work but for some reason the way I have it coded is causing none of the other options to be selectable.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNATk/182/) that I modified to give you an example of the issue I am seeing.

```
HTML:
<div id="form">
<div class="pad" style="top:0px">Programmatic:
    <select id="stateSelect">
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
Javascript:
require([
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/json",
"dijit/form/Form",
"dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
"dojo/parser",
"dojo/domReady!"], function (construct, JSON, Form, CheckedMultiSelect) {
var form, div = construct.create('div', {
    'class': 'pad',
    style: 'bottom:0px'
}, 'form');
getValues = function () {
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(form.get('value'));
    stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']); // CANNOT unselect this value
};
var stateSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect({
    dropDown: true,
    labelText: 'States',
    multiple: true,
    name: 'state',
    onChange: getValues,
    required: false
}, "stateSelect");
form = new Form({
    style: 'display:block'
}, 'form');
form.startup();
stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']); // default selected value
});
```

What I need is the top option to be default selected and you cannot unselect it even by clicking it, but I still need the others to be selectable.

EDIT: After working on this extensively I believe the issue is that every time the onChange event is fired I am telling it to set the first option to be selected which is calling the onChange event to be fired again.

I have tried various methods of trying to "disconnect" the setting but I cannot get anything to work.

Here are some links to what I have tried:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/disconnect.html
[Dojo Select onChange event firing when changing value programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229747/dojo-select-onchange-event-firing-when-changing-value-programatically?rq=1)

I even tried to add the third parameter to the set method to false with no luck

```
stateSelect.set('value', ['CA'], false); // CANNOT unselect this value
```

I really would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about a year late. I came across this while searching for something unrelated and thought I may be able to give an answer that may help someone else who also ran into the issue you had.

You were on the right track with:

```
stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']);
```

As you have noted though, this will replace any value that you select.  I would recommend to check for the existence of your required value and append it to the list of values if it's not there so your getValues function becomes:

```
getValues = function () {        
    var selectedValues = stateSelect.get('value');
    var requiredValue = 'CA';
    if (arrayUtil.indexOf(selectedValues, requiredValue) == -1) {
        selectedValues.push(requiredValue);
        stateSelect.set("value", selectedValues);
    }
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(form.get('value'));
    //stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']); // CANNOT unselect this value
};
```

Notice the use of arrayUtil.  In order to use this, you'll need to update your require statement like so:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/json",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (arrayUtil, construct, JSON, Form, CheckedMultiSelect) {
```

Your complete code would look like this:

```
require([
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dojo/json",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (arrayUtil, construct, JSON, Form, CheckedMultiSelect) {
    var form, div = construct.create('div', {
        'class': 'pad',
        style: 'bottom:0px'
    }, 'form');
    getValues = function () {        
        var selectedValues = stateSelect.get('value');
        var requiredValue = 'CA';
        if (arrayUtil.indexOf(selectedValues, requiredValue) == -1) {
            selectedValues.push(requiredValue);
            stateSelect.set("value", selectedValues);
        }
        div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(form.get('value'));
        //stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']); // CANNOT unselect this value
    };
    var stateSelect = new CheckedMultiSelect({
        dropDown: true,
        labelText: 'States',
        multiple: true,
        name: 'state',
        onChange: getValues,
        required: false
    }, "stateSelect");
    form = new Form({
        style: 'display:block'
    }, 'form');
    form.startup();
    stateSelect.set('value', ['CA']); // default selected value
});
```