# Dojo Slider onChange event firing when changing value programmatically

Tags: dojo, slideshow

I have multiple interconnected Dojo HorizontalSlider. In the onChange event of the sliders the values of the other sliders are updated. Changing the value programmatically fires the onChange event of the corresponding slider, which again fires its own onChange event and overrides the values.

I do need to set intermediateChanges = true, which makes the priorityChange flag useless in this case. Also i tried setting up a variable that checks whether one slider is active, but due to timing issues this does not work as well.

Simplified example with two sliders:

```
var sliding = false;

var slider1 = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 70,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 100,
                discreteValues: 101,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                onChange: function() {
                    if (sliding == false) {
                        sliding = true;
                        new_value = [...]
                        slider2.set("value", new_value, false);
                    };
                    sliding = false;
                }
            }, "slider1");

var slider2 = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 30,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 100,
                discreteValues: 101,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                onChange: function() {
                    if (sliding == false) {
                        sliding = true;
                        new_value = [...]
                        slider1.set("value", new_value, false);
                    };
                    sliding = false;
                }
            }, "slider2");

slider1.startup();
slider2.startup();
```

I also found this example, which seems to address the same problem with Dojo Select: [Dojo Select onChange event firing when changing value programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229747/dojo-select-onchange-event-firing-when-changing-value-programatically)

How to prevent firing the onChange event of a slider when changing its value programmatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bit ugly, but you could do this:

```
var sliding = false;

var slider1 = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 70,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 100,
                discreteValues: 101,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                onChange: function() {
                    if (sliding == false) {
                        sliding = true;
                        new_value = [...]
                        slider2.set("intermediateChanges", false);
                        slider2.set("value", new_value, false);
                        slider2.set("intermediateChanges", true);
                    };
                    sliding = false;
                }
            }, "slider1");

var slider2 = new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 30,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 100,
                discreteValues: 101,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                onChange: function() {
                    if (sliding == false) {
                        sliding = true;
                        new_value = [...]
                        slider1.set("intermediateChanges", false);
                        slider1.set("value", new_value, false);
                        slider1.set("intermediateChanges", true);
                    };
                    sliding = false;
                }
            }, "slider2");

slider1.startup();
slider2.startup();
```