# Possible bug - Event change fires after widget.set('options', [])

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

Currently I am using [dijit/form/Select](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/Select) to display a list of options and I need to programmatically update content for the `dijit/form/Select`.

Currently I am using `.set('value', ...);` but I have noticed that event `change` is fired (which is in my case is not wanted).

I need to be able to update the widget and selecting a value without having fired `change` event.

The `change` event, afaik, it should be fired only when an user "change" the value of the Select list clicking on it.

```js
require(["dijit/form/Select",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Select) {

  var options = [{
    label: "TN",
    value: "Tennessee"
  }, {
    label: "VA",
    value: "Virginia",
    selected: true
  }, {
    label: "WA",
    value: "Washington"
  }, {
    label: "FL",
    value: "Florida"
  }, {
    label: "CA",
    value: "California"
  }];

  var s = new Select({
    options: options
  }, "target");
  s.startup();

  s.on("change", function() {
    console.log("my value: " + s.get("value"))
  });

  // updating options
  options.push({
    label: "MI",
    value: "Milan",
    selected: true
  });
  s.set('options', options);
  s.reset();
  // issue here, the following line trigger event change
  s.set('value', 'mi');

})
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @PatrickBarr thanks for your comment, sorry but this question is related to dojo and not jQuery.

Comment: Sorry about that I just saw `.on("change")` and ignored the tags

Comment: @PatrickBarr no problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around to this issue using:

```
  myWidget.set('_onChangeActive', false); // prevent firing change
  myWidget.set('value', 'Milan', false);
  myWidget.set('_onChangeActive', true); // reset to default
```

which works also when using `.set()` consecutively on multiple widgets.

Also passing false as third argument to `.set()` works if you change only one widget at a time.

```
s.set('value', 'Milan', false);
```

Notes:  I could not find reference in the official documentation for this third argument using `.set()`:

Related question:
[Dojo Select onChange event firing when changing value programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229747/dojo-select-onchange-event-firing-when-changing-value-programatically?rq=1)

```js
require(["dijit/form/Select",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Select) {

  var options = [{
    label: "TN",
    value: "Tennessee"
  }, {
    label: "VA",
    value: "Virginia",
    selected: true
  }, {
    label: "WA",
    value: "Washington"
  }, {
    label: "FL",
    value: "Florida"
  }, {
    label: "CA",
    value: "California"
  }];

  var s = new Select({
    options: options
  }, "target");
  s.startup();

  s.on("change", function() {
    console.log("my value: " + s.get("value"))
  });

  // updating options
  options.push({
    label: "MI",
    value: "Milan",
    selected: true
  });

  s.set('options', options);
  s.reset();

  s.set('_onChangeActive', false); // prevent firing change
  s.set('value', 'Milan', false);
  s.set('_onChangeActive', true);

})
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: [API docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.6/dijit/form/Select#_setValueAttr) (methods -> _setValueAttr) for version 1.6 mentions this, in current version private methods aren't described.

Answer (score 3):

`_setValueAttr` has also second parameter - `priorityChange`. If you set it to false, `onChange` event won't be fired.

From [API docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.6/dijit/form/Select) version 1.6 (see _setValueAttr in methods):

> _setValueAttr 
> Overrides dijit.form._FormValueWidget, dijit.form._FormSelectWidget
>   Sets the value of the widget. **If the value has changed, then fire onChange event, unless priorityChange is specified as null (or false?)**

BTW. If you want to add one option there's no need to replace whole set of options - you can call `s.addOption(newOption)`

```js
require(["dijit/form/Select",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Select) {

  var options = [{
    label: "TN",
    value: "Tennessee"
  }, {
    label: "VA",
    value: "Virginia",
    selected: true
  }, {
    label: "WA",
    value: "Washington"
  }, {
    label: "FL",
    value: "Florida"
  }, {
    label: "CA",
    value: "California"
  }];

  var s = new Select({
    options: options
  }, "target");
  s.startup();

  s.on("change", function() {
    console.log("my value: " + s.get("value"))
  });

  // updating options
  options.push({
    label: "MI",
    value: "Milan",
    selected: true
  });
  s.set('options', options);
  s.reset();
  // issue here, the following line trigger event change
  s.set('value', 'Milan', false);

})
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<body class="claro">
<div id="target"></div>
</body>
```